# Не подгружает css в GetSimple CMS

Tags: apache, php, cms

Скачал getSimple Cms,устанавливаю.Установка идёт без стилей,видно что форма съехала.После установки меня кидает в админку,с краказябрами вместо русского текста и с отсутствием каких либо стилей.Причём если выйти из папки /admin и зайти просто на сайт,а не в админ панель,то русский отображается идеально,как доктор прописал и стили все подргужены.В чём может быть проблема?Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data/other/website.xml - лежит жёстко указаный путь который надо изменить при переносе сайта